# "Заливной" или "заливочный"?

Tags: лингвистика

*Заливной* или *заливочный* пенопласт?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, технические термины не всегда следуют языковой логике, но если иходить из значений слова, то и то и другое одинаково плохо.

У "заливной" нет подходящего значения.

*ЗАЛИВНОЙ, -ая, -ое.
...
2. Спец. Предназначенный, служащий для заливания, заливки. З-ая тара.
...*
©Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
(другие значения - из другой области).

Т.е. "заливной" - то, с помощью чего заливают, а не то, чем.

Но и "заливочный" - полный синоним этого значения:
*Предназначенный, служащий для заливки. З-ая форма.*

Остаётся только дождаться, когда слово будет зафиксировано общелитературными словарями.

Answer (score 0):

я думаю что заливочный